# can jackson serialize full version including @JsonIgnore?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I want to serialize an object using java jackson.

I want to serialize it once in a short version

and second in a full version.

I have added a @JsonIgnore annotation over the non-mandatory fields.

But how can I tell jackson to serialize all fields including @JsonIgnore when desired?

Comment: You'd have to provide a different serialization configuration to the ObjectMapper, or maybe use Modules... There are quite a few solutions

Comment: Or just use different wrapper classes

Comment: @fge but what feature do I need to turn off in the configuration? i didn't find any relevant

Comment: @cy3er what do you mean deep copy the full object to a partial one?

Comment: @fge how can i use module? can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to ignore `@JsonIgnore`. I can think of 2 approaches:

1. Extend `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, over `hasIgnoreMarker(...)` method (I think that's the name -- can check javadocs)
2. Add `@JsonIgnore(false)` annotation override using "mix-in annotations": `false` means "do not ignore", and is explicitly allowed to be used (default value is `true`) for such overrides.

However: a better way would be to use JSON Views, or JSON filters.